# XSL if column X is character X the do this else do that

Tags: xslt

-XSL Version 1.0 -

I have an XSL file that was created by someone that no longer works at my company and of course we need to change the XSL.  I have never used XSL but did some searching and believe I can perform the function needed by updating the XSL with a choose function.

*-Issue-*
We have a field that was changed from a leading character count of 13 to 11 but we need to capture both for some time period. It was decided to trim the two leading characters of the year.  The values will remain constant up to the slash "/" at either 13 or 11 characters, characters after can vary from 5-13 characters.

- 13 characters CTM08G2012001/0001
- 11 characters CTM08G12001/0001

I want to check to see if the 12th character is a "/" and if it is use the first 11 characters and if it is not use the first 13 characters. Here is the code for the function.

1. Where would I put the choose/otherwise function?  There appears to be several that repeat themselves and this confuses me.
2. How do I capture the "/" in the specific string?

I will continue to research and do apologize for not having a list of things tried as I am not sure where to even start.

```
<func:function name="func:getProjClaimNo">
      <xsl:param name='Proj' />
      <xsl:param name='Claim' />

      <xsl:variable name="isNUMB"       select="'1234567890'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vProj1"        select="substring($Proj, 8, 1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vProj2"        select="substring($Proj, 9, 1)"/>

      <xsl:choose>  <!-- 1 -->
           <xsl:when test="contains($isNUMB,$vProj1)">                                                  <!-- 1 -->
            <xsl:choose>                                                                        <!-- 2 -->
                <xsl:when test="contains($isNUMB,$vProj2)">                                         <!-- 2 -->
                    <xsl:variable name="vProj3"        select="number(substring($Proj, 8, 2))"/>
                    <xsl:choose>                                                                <!-- 3 -->
                        <xsl:when test="$vProj3 &gt; 8">                                            <!-- 3 -->
                                <func:result select="$Proj"/>
                        </xsl:when>                                                         <!-- 3 -->
                        <xsl:otherwise>                                                     <!-- 3 -->
                            <!-- May need to check to see if claim number is empty or if proj in table -->
                            <xsl:choose>
                                                                                        <!-- 4 -->
                                <xsl:when test="$Claim=''">                                     <!-- 4 -->
                                        <func:result select="substring($Claim, 1, 13)"/>
                                </xsl:when>                                                 <!-- 4 -->
                                <xsl:otherwise>                                             <!-- 4 -->
                                        <func:result select="substring($Claim, 1, 13)"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>                                                <!-- 4 -->
                                </xsl:choose>                                                       <!-- 4 -->
                        </xsl:otherwise>                                                        <!-- 3 -->
                        </xsl:choose>                                                               <!-- 3 -->
                </xsl:when>                                                                 <!-- 2 -->
                <xsl:otherwise>                                                             <!-- 2 -->
                    <!-- May need to check to see if claim number is empty -->
                    <xsl:choose>                                                                <!-- 5 -->
                        <xsl:when test="$Claim=''">                                             <!-- 5 -->
                                <func:result select="substring($Claim, 1, 13)"/>
                        </xsl:when>                                                         <!-- 5 -->
                        <xsl:otherwise>                                                     <!-- 5 -->
                                <func:result select="substring($Claim, 1, 13)"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>                                                        <!-- 5 -->
                        </xsl:choose>                                                               <!-- 5 -->
                </xsl:otherwise>                                                                <!-- 2 -->
            </xsl:choose>                                                                       <!-- 2 -->
           </xsl:when>                                                                          <!-- 1 -->
           <xsl:otherwise>                                                                      <!-- 1 -->
                <!-- May need to check to see if claim number is empty -->
            <xsl:choose>                                                                        <!-- 6 -->
                <xsl:when test="$Claim=''">                                                     <!-- 6 -->
                        <func:result select="substring($Claim, 1, 13)"/>
                </xsl:when>                                                                 <!-- 6 -->
                <xsl:otherwise>                                                             <!-- 6 -->
                        <func:result select="substring($Claim, 1, 13)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>                                                                <!-- 6 -->
                </xsl:choose>                                                                       <!-- 6 -->
           </xsl:otherwise>                                                                     <!-- 1 -->
      </xsl:choose>                                                                             <!-- 1 -->
 </func:function>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where that "field" is in your stylesheet snippet. In general, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring($yourfield, 12, 1) ='/'">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($yourfield, 1, 11)"/>   
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($yourfield, 1, 13)"/>   
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

or, more succinctly:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($yourfield, 1, 13-2*(substring($yourfield, 12, 1) ='/'))"/>
```

However, If I understand correctly, it could be much simpler:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($yourfield, '/')"/>
```

Comment: The last one is simple and efficient...I am very appreciative of the response.  I will test all scenarios and provide my results.  Thanks so much!!!!